# How to pass arguments in threading Timer?

Tags: python

This is what I have so far:

```
def start(variable):
    thread = threading.Timer(1, start, args=variable).start()
    # do something
```

But is giving me an error. What is the correct way to do this?

Error:

```
TypeError: start() takes 1 positional argument but 6 were given
```

Comment: Do what exactly? What error?

Comment: Use `args=(variable,)` or `args=[variable]`.

Comment: Or `{variable}`. Even `{variable: None}` would probably work. Basically, any iterable should work.